# Angular - how to print value of key value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, doctrine-orm

I have $scope.count that I want to show count of specific data in my table. I made this :

```
$result = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('count(u.teamId)')
    ->from('mypath\Entities\Teams', 'u')
    ->where('u.teamType =:teamType')
    ->setParameters(['teamType' => 4  ])
    ->getQuery()
    ->getScalarResult();
return $result;
```

I save it's result in *$scope.count*:

```
<label class="btn btn-yellow force-btn">Model = {{ count }} </label>
```

result of $scope.count is :

```
[{"1":"2"}]
```

Although , I want to show just *2* . Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <label class="btn btn-yellow force-btn">Model = {{ count[0]["1"] }} </label>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working . but how count[0]["1"] works?

Comment: count[0] is {"1","2"} and ["1"] is key for that object.

Comment: so How to retrieve "1" instead of "2"?

Comment: loop object in controller and return key of that object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resvalue;
    $.each(c,function(key,value){
    resvalue=value[1]
    })
```